# Search for android code to chew up memory

Tags: android, memory

I want to debug my app. I hope some soft or code could chew up memory and make my activity re Oncreate. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rotate the screen (e.g., `<Ctrl>-<F11>` on Windows or Linux) to force a configuration change, which will cause Android to destroy and recreate your activity.

"Chew up memory" within your process will simply cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.